# How to clear table widget pyqt5 in order to add new content

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I've been trying to figure out how to clear  tableWidget so i can add new content. The snippet below shows the widget and how the information is added. However, anytime i refresh it, instead of clearing the screen it rather add more information.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

```
   def addNewContent(results):
        header = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader()
        self.tableWidget.clearContents()

        header.setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        numrows = len(results)
        numcols = len(results[0])

        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(numrows)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(numcols)

        for row in range(numrows):
            for column in range(numcols):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(row, column, QTableWidgetItem((str(results[row][column]))))

    addNewContent(results)
```

Comment: provide  a [mre], change `self.tableWidget.clearContents()` to `self.tableWidget.clear()`

Answer (score 0):

I've searched a lot for this problem the only solution that I came up with, was to call `model.clear()` and then setting the header labels once again

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in the variable result i believe its a list so all what you have to do is reinitialize it then append it with the new values somewhere in your code